# Cannot connect to CloudSQL via Cloud SQL Node.js Connector using Sequelize, but able to connect through Postgres

Tags: google-cloud-platform, sequelize.js, google-cloud-sql, sequelize-typescript

Trying to connect to GCP CloudSQL Postgres databsae externally outside of GCP and am trying to use the **Cloud SQL Node.js Connector** package.

I am using Sequelize as my ORM to connect to my postgres database, and when I use the examaples to add in the connection options, my database throws a connection error.

However when i try and connect directly to the databse using the **pg** package and use add in the connection options from the Cloud SQL Connector package, I am able to connect to the database and run queries.

The issue is that i want to use sequelize and sequelize typescript for the models, in the docs it says - *Sequelize examples require Sequelize >=v7.0.0-alpha.27 (`npm install @sequelize/core`)*. Using this package instead of the default sequelize package allows me to connect, but i can't use the sequelize-typescript package with this version.

Has anyone had the same issue with connecting to a GCP Cloud SQL database?

Here is some code examples to show what

```
const connector = new Connector()

const clientOpts = await connector.getOptions({
    instanceConnectionName: "instanceConnectionName",
    ipType: IpAddressTypes.PUBLIC,
    authType: AuthTypes.PASSWORD
})

// Connect through sequelize
// Using "@sequelize/core" this works but using "sequelize" and "sequelize-typescript" this fails
const sequelize = new Sequelize({
    dialect: "postgres",
    dialectModule: pg,
    username: "postgres",
    password: "password",
    database: "database",
    dialectOptions: {
        ...clientOpts
    }
})

await sequelize.authenticate()




// Connect direct via "pg" - this works
const { Pool } = pg

const pool = new Pool({
    ...clientOpts,
    username: "postgres",
    password: "password",
    database: "database",
    max: 5
})
const { rows } = await pool.query("SELECT * FROM public.users")
console.table(rows)
```

Currently using:

```
- "sequelize": "6.33.0"
- "sequelize-typescript": "2.1.5"
- "pg": "8.11.3"
- "pg-hstore": "2.3.4"
- "@google-cloud/cloud-sql-connector": "1.2.1"
```

Comment: Your post is very confusing on what works and what does not. First state the problem and include exact error messages for your code. At the end, you can add additional information such as what works, but focus on the actual problem.

Answer (score 1):

As you stated in your question, `sequelize@6` is NOT supported by the **Cloud SQL Node.js Connector** and will not work.

You should remove the `sequelize` and `sequelize-typescript` and add `@sequelize/core` instead:

```
$ npm uninstall sequelize sequelize-typescript
$ npm install @sequelize/core
```

From a [quick search](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize-typescript/issues/1564), it looks like when using Sequelize 7+ (`@sequelize/core`) the `sequelize-typescript` package is no longer needed since the TypeScript decorators should already be included in that package.